# How to give different metrics tags for different controllers in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

In Spring Boot 2.0.2 is it possible to use one meterRegistry bean for all controllers while giving each controller its own set of commonTags. For example in my `Application.java` I define the following.

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<PrometheusMeterRegistry> metrics() {
  return registry -> registry.config().commonTags("messageType", "x");
}
```

Then when I register any meters to the `registry` they will have this `messageType = x`. Is it possible to define within this bean what `commonTags` will register when any function gets executed within the scope of Controller?

If so how? Does this need to be done within controller itself?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way for meter's that are registered in a specific context to automatically get a tag. **Short answer: you'll have to add the tag manually yourself.**

You could use a `MeterFilter` to inspect `Meter`s as they are registered and add tags there based on the meter's name.

Keep in mind that tags are best used to represent a subset of a measurement:

```
db.request.total{queryType=userLookup}
db.request.total{queryType=groupLookup}
db.request.total{queryType=userUpdate}
```

This is the recommended way to use tags because then you can determine how many of a given request are being made and which might be the path that needs to be optimized for speed.

```
db.request.total{caller=controller}
db.request.total{caller=notAController}
```

Breaking up metric by caller won't be useful in that case.